# HAC Standard Errors - Number of Lags in an Unbalanced Panel

Tags: panel-data, standard-error, neweywest, hac

I am working on a panel dataset with a lot of missing data. Because I have reason to believe that the error terms are autocorrelated, I want to use HAC (Newey West) standard errors. I am unsure how to choose how many lags to include. In a typical time series analysis (i.e. not in a panel), people often suggest setting the number of lags to $T^{\frac14}$. However, for an unbalanced panel, I am unsure if I should use the longest available time series or the shortest available time series for $T$. The length of the time series of different entities in my sample varies significantly so that if I use the length of the longest time series for $T$, the number of lags suggested by $T^{\frac14}$ would be longer than the entire time series I have for some entities. Would this make the model misspecified?

A different thing that might affect my choice of the lags to include is that I expect there is a particular autocorrelation structure. I have monthly level data, and once a year, something happens that shakes up the correlation between data points. Thus, an observation from January of a year will have low autocorrelation to an observation from December of the preceding year, but an observation from December will be correlated with all 11 preceding months of the year.

Answer (score 0):

I found a reference for the number of lags, and the correct choice is to use the length of the longest time series minus 1 for the lag parameter. The reference is:

Mitchell A. Petersen, Estimating Standard Errors in Finance Panel Data Sets: Comparing Approaches, The Review of Financial Studies, Volume 22, Issue 1, January 2009, Pages 435–480

I am still unsure how to deal with the particular correlation structure.